# Read csv and update csv

Tags: shell, unix

I have csv file which has list of hadoop file path, so I have to read each hadoop file from each row and calling hadoop - get. It is working fine. But I would like to mark the csv 2nd column with files are copied to destination folder.

something like flag. How to do edit the second column in while loop and save it in same csv?

Input.csv

path,flag
file1path,
file2path,

So after copying each file want to mark flag as Y in the same file.

Comment: If you are reading in a shell script, it would be easier to write each file and flag out to a temporary file (before or after calling hadoop on the file), then when done with the loop move the temp file in place of the original.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.

Comment: Good deal, glad it worked. There's always more than one way to *skin the cat* in shell programming `:)`